# Calculus - What is the meaning of the Limit of a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition

Just a simple question. What is the meaning of $\lim _{h \to 0}(g'(x))$? I mean, that appeared in a proof and they simply assumed that this is equal to $g'(x)$ I guess. Since the definition of the derivative of $g(x)$ is in itself a limit, what is the meaning of writing a limit of a limit? ( i know its meaningful when when take different variables tending to some value, but what happens when its just one- in this case, $h$?)

I know this is simple, but I am trying to build my foundations.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}(g^\prime (x))$ is nonsense because there is no explicit $h$ in the argument.  It is as meaningless as $\lim\limits_{s \to 0}(g^\prime (x))$, or ...

Comment: $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}(g^\prime (x)) = g^\prime (x)$, but is this what you want?

Comment: In this case $\lim_{h\to 0}g'(x)=g'(x)\lim_{h\to 0}1=g'(x)$

Comment: The derivative is defined by a limit but the derivative function $g’(x)$ is just a function. As you wrote it the limit is just $g’(x)$ (assuming $g’(x)$ be not depend on $h$).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. It doesn't have to be nonsense. It's fine to write for example $\lim_{h\to0} 5=5$ even if there is no $h$ in the expression $5$.

Comment: @md2perpe:  It makes little sense *in this context* where the OP asks about the limit of a limit.  As zkutch asks "is this what you want?"  I have a very strong sense that the OP is confused beyond the goals of this question and doesn't realize the proper role of taking the limit.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork my question was essentially: Imagine you have a simple F(x), whit only one argument ( the x). What sense does i make to write something like lim(z->1) f(x), since in f(x) there is no variable z?

Comment: Then why oh *WHY* did you choose your $F(x)$ to be a DERIVATIVE, $g^\prime (x)$?!  Thoroughly confused.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Context is missing. Without the context we cannot know why that limit appears.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork you are totally right. i used the derivative (and that created confusion) because the proof in which my doubt appeared was about the derivatives. Maybe i should have used other function! On the other have, i was really thinking if THE fact that the function in question was a derivative played a role in my doubts. That's why i used it

Answer (score 1):

Take a simpler example: $\lim_{x \rightarrow1}\lim_{y \rightarrow2} x+y$.
First, we calculate the $y$-limit, treating $x$ as a parameter. We get $\lim_{x \rightarrow1} x+2$. Then we preform the second limit, getting $1+2=3$. The same works for more complicated limits, like the derivative. Note that we need to use different letters for our dummy-variables. In your case, the expression $g'(x)$ does not depend on $h$, so the limit is just $g'(x)$. We could have written $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \lim_{d \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x+d)-g(x)}{d}=\lim_{d \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x+d)-g(x)}{d} =g'(x)$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you so much! In your last example, I was scared of removing the "limit when h->0" cause it looked like nonsense. Glad you clarified!